# Redirection to login on user auth with Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I have a Laravel 5.2 application running ok in the live server. It was also running ok in a Ubuntu 14.04 with Apache server.

Now I am using a MAC so I made a fresh installation of my App using the MAMP PRO application. All is runing ok in Frontend but when I try to login to the backend there is a redirection that doesn't allow me to be authenticated. The DB is exactly the same, so the user should be authenticated.

When I type user and password and the hit send the screen shows:

```
Redirecting to http://localhost/admin/dashboard
```

Then the screen refresh again and shows:

```
Redirecting to http://localhost/admin/auth/login
```

I have think that maybe it is related to the Session, but it is stablished to:

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
```

So I do not know why this can be a reason. Any idea?

---

UPDATE - I include a summary of routes.php

This is my routes.php file (chunks of it)

```
// Admin area
Route::get('admin', function () {
  return redirect('/admin/dashboard');
});

Route::group([
  'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin',
  'middleware' => 'auth.admin',
], function () {

  Route::get('admin/dashboard'        , 'AdminController@index');

});

Route::get('admin/auth/login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth\AuthController@login');
```

Comment: Check the permission of the storage folder. There must be a sessions folder under storage/framework/ with the read and write permission. Try to set the permission of storage folder as 777 and execute.

Comment: Can you share your `route.php` here?

Comment: smartrahat I've included the routes.php

Comment: plz check the php version required by laravel 5.2 on your server, maybe that is causing this problem as the code you say is same.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like your routes aren't in the `web` middleware. Make sure all the routes that require cookies or the session are defined like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
  Route::get('your-route-here', 'SomeController@method');
});
```

This is a new feature in Laravel 5.2.

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. In my live server I also updated to Laravel 5.2 and it's working.